# Month/Day comparison in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm not an expert in JavaScript, but I've been tasked with migrating a very large website that was coded into PHP into a new CMS that does not allow server-side languages. I am therefore spending my days converting many PHP date-calcs to JavaScript.

Something very simple in PHP:

```
<?php 
if (date('md') < 816) {$award_year = date('Y');}
if (date('md') > 815) {$award_year = date('Y') + 1;}
/*echo "year ".$award_year;*/
?>
```

This allows the year an application is due to automatically change to next year after August 15.

I've been trying to recreate this effect with Javascript and here is what I have come up with:

```
var today = new Date();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0! 
var dd = today.getday();
if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0'+mm
} 

currDate = mmdd;
var currDate = new Date(); 
var appDate = new Date("0816");

if (currDate < appDate){
var printDate = theDate.getFullYear();  
}

else if (currDate >= appDate){
var printDate = theDate.getFullYear()+1;      
}
```

I know that I am missing something, because the var currDate cannot just = mmdd and then be compared to another date. Can someone help me with the next step here ? I'm trying to actually learn JavaScript as I go rather than just blindly fix issues.

Comment: how can a CMS not allow server side languages? How would it even know?

Comment: What CMS is this?

Comment: `if (date('md') < 816)` that is comparing a string with an integer. Why are you doing that? Use proper date comparisons instead.

Comment: @delboy1978uk I don't know, but I know PHP is not supported.

Comment: @Andreas please read the question. And anyhow, its perfectly valid in php to do that as it correctly type casts to the appropriate int. Try it if you don't believe me.

Comment: @Andreas That was not my question. I did not write the PHP, i'm trying to replace it with Javascript that serves the same function.

Comment: @beingbecoming I better suggest you to use `moment.js`

Comment: If you can call a URL via AJAX or whatever, again I ask how can the CMS tell PHP was involved, when PHP never returns PHP code? You'll get HTML, JSON, whatever back, but no PHP

Comment: @PraveenKumar I am trying to avoid using moment.js and to learn to code these basic date calculations myself.

Comment: What CMS is this?

Comment: @beingbecoming Ah okay... `:)`

Comment: @IncredibleHat Building a code that relies on typecasting is not recomended by anyone. Well, wait maybe I should have asked you first, What do you think?

Comment: @delboy1978uk What difference does it make? That is not my question anyway. PHP won't work with this particular service.

Comment: i'm trying to tell you so you understand, if you can call a URL, it doesn't matter what is on the server, PHP, ASP, JSP, whatever, you don't get to see that. You could easily make a url on a server with php that does the above php code above and returns data as JSON. Not saying that's what you __should__ do, just that the CMS has no way of knowing you called PHP

Comment: @dellboy1968uk I understand, but I'm telling you it won't work. From the CMS support "xxxxxx does not run PHP services, so they are not supported in content zones or within the resource manager."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will look similar to your PHP code:

```js
const date = new Date();
const day = date.getUTCDate();
const month = date.getMonth();
const md = month + "" + day;

if (md < 816) {
 var award_year = date.getFullYear();
}
else if (md > 815) {
 var award_year = date.getFullYear() + 1;
}

console.log(award_year);
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of combining strings and comparing two dates you could check the current day and month to determine which year to return.

For example,

```
function getAwardYear() {
  const today = new Date()
  const AUGUST = 7

  if (today.getMonth() >= AUGUST && today.getDate() > 15) {
    return today.getFullYear() + 1
  }

  return today.getFullYear()
}

// Today: 6th Jun 2018
getAwardYear() // 2018

// Today: 16th Aug 2018
getAwardYear() // 2019
```

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense to me and is much simpler than what i was trying to do. Thank you for taking the time to help me as this bit of code is a good learning experience for me! Have a great day

Comment: Wouldn't August be 9 in JavaScript (0 = January?)

Comment: @beingbecoming, I'm glad it helped. Since it's zero indexed as you mentioned you subtract one from the number - January is the 1st month so becomes 0, August is the 8th month so becomes 7. You can try this out in the devtools, e.g. `new Date('2018/08/16').getMonth() // 7`

Comment: @beingbecoming .... u can try this on your own in jsfiddle instead of asking these questions....

Comment: Thank you @Craig Ayre I misunderstood something clearly but this is very helpful and I think it will help me with many more calcs in the future

Answer (score 1):

I know there is plenty of things to improvise the below code... I am leaving it for you to improvise...

```js
var today = new Date();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0! 
var dd = today.getDay();
if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0'+mm
} 
var yyyy="2018"

var currDate = new Date(yyyy+"-"+mm+"-"+dd); 
var appDate = new Date("2018-01-16");

alert("appDate"+appDate);
alert("currDate"+currDate);

if (currDate < appDate){
var printDate = currDate.getFullYear();  
alert(printDate);
}
else if (currDate >= appDate){
var printDate = appDate.getFullYear()+1;    
alert(printDate);
    }
```